# Uniform angular velocity equation

Tags: calculus, physics

I have arrived to the following equations in polar coordinates

$$\vec{v}=\dot{r}\hat{r}+r\dot{\theta}\hat{\theta}$$

$$\vec{a}=(\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2 )\hat{r}+(2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}+r\ddot{\theta})\hat{\theta}$$

Then in the lecture note it is written that if the movement is in uniform angular velocity $\omega = \dot{\theta}$ in radius $R$ then 
$$\vec{a}=-R\omega^2\hat{r}$$

How did he arrived to this formula? maybe I written the formula wrong

Comment: If $r=R$ which is a constant, what happens when you calculate $\dot{r}$ and $\ddot{r}$? After that think about $ \ddot{\theta}$.

Comment: @JamesArathoon So we have $\vec{a}=-R\omega^2\hat{r}+R\dot{\omega}\hat{\omega}$ or $\omega$ is also constant?

Comment: Uniform angular velocity would mean $\omega$ is a constant, right?

Comment: Keep $\hat{\theta}$ as the unit vector. Yes uniform angular velocity is just another way of saying constant angular velocity $\omega = \dot{\theta}=\text{constant angular velocity}$. So all you need to ask now is what is the value of the angular acceleration $\ddot{\theta}$.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\vec a = -R\omega^2 \vec r$ in your last equation?  And not $\vec a = -R\omega^2 \hat r$? Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis corrected it is $\hat{r}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's sort out the notation:  I take it that our OP newhere intends the "hat" symbol, as in "$\hat x$", to indicate a unit vector in the direction of $\vec x \ne 0$:

$\hat x = \dfrac{\vec x}{\vert \vec x \vert}, \tag 1$

where the customary "arrow" is used for general vectors as in "$\vec x$"

Second, the derivations of

$\vec v = \dot r \hat r + r\dot \theta \hat \theta  \tag 2$

and

$\vec a = (\ddot r - r\dot \theta^2) \hat r + (2\dot r \dot \theta + r \ddot \theta)\hat \theta \tag 3$

are in their own right worthy of presentation:

We may introduce cartesian coordinates $(x, y)$ on $\Bbb R^2$ such that

$x = r \cos \theta, \tag 4$

$y = r \sin \theta; \tag 5$

if we write

$\vec r = (x, y) = (r\cos \theta, r \sin \theta) = r(\cos \theta, \sin \theta), \tag 6$

we see that

$\vec n = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta) \tag 7$

is the unit vector in the radial ($r$) direction, that is

$\hat r = \vec n; \tag 8$

the unit vector $\hat \theta$ in the $\theta$ direction is tangent to the curve (6) with constant $r$ at any point $(x, y) \ne (0, 0)$; thus it must be collinear with

$\dfrac{d{\vec n(\theta)}}{d\theta} = (-\sin \theta, \cos \theta); \tag 9$

since

$\left \vert \dfrac{d{\vec n(\theta)}}{d\theta} \right \vert = 1, \tag{10}$

we infer that

$\hat \theta = (-\sin \theta, \cos \theta) = \dfrac{d{\vec n(\theta)}}{d\theta} \tag{11}$

for $\theta$ increasing in the counter-clockwise direction.

Now any curve

$\phi(t): I \to \Bbb R^2, \tag{12}$

where $I \subset \Bbb R$ is some open interval, may be written

$\phi(t) = r(t)\vec n(\theta(t)) = r(t)(\cos \theta(t), \sin \theta(t)); \tag{13}$

thus,

$\vec v = \dot \phi(t) = \dot r(t) \vec n(\theta) + r(t) \dot{\vec n(\theta)}; \tag{14}$

by virtue of (7)-(11) this may be written

$\vec v = \dot \phi(t) = \dot r(t) \hat r + r(t) \dot \theta \hat \theta, \tag{15}$

thus establishing (2).  We may then differentiate this equation and find

$\vec a = \dot{\vec v} = \ddot r \hat r + \dot r \dot{\hat r} + \dot r \dot \theta \hat \theta + r \ddot \theta \hat \theta + r\dot \theta \dot{\hat \theta}; \tag{16}$

between (7)-(11) we see that

$\dot{\hat r} = \dot \theta \hat \theta, \tag{17}$

$\dot{\hat \theta} = -\dot \theta \hat r; \tag{18}$

assembling (16)-(18) together we reach

$\vec a = \ddot r \hat r + \dot r \dot\theta \hat \theta + \dot r \dot \theta \hat \theta + r \ddot \theta \hat \theta - r\dot \theta^2 \hat r$
$= (\ddot r - r\dot \theta^2)\hat r + (2\dot r \dot \theta + r\ddot \theta) \hat \theta, \tag{19}$

which is (3).

Having derived (2) and (3), we take

$r = R = \text{constant} \tag{20}$

and

$\omega = \dot \theta = \text{constant}, \tag{21}$

so that

$\dot r = \ddot r = \dot \omega = \ddot \theta = 0; \tag{22}$

then (19) yields

$\vec a = -R\omega^2 \hat r, \tag{23}$

as was to be shown.

Comment: typo in (22), should read  $\ddot \theta$ (or perhaps $\dot \omega$)

Comment: @JamesArathoon:  yes you are right.  Will correct.  Thanks!